# Dynamic Background image with color overlay syntax - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, dynamic, background

I am using Ionic(based on Angular) and I want to set an image as a background of a component with a color overlay above it. The code is correct when written into the .css file, however when it is dynamic(I substitute the values with variables) my syntax seems to not be right.

This does not affect the background of my component at all:

```
[ngStyle] = "{'background': 'linear-gradient('+colors[test.number]+','+colors[0]+'),url(../assets/img/test-'+test.number+'.jpg)'}"
```

However, this works but does not put an image as a background, only the color:

```
[ngStyle] = "{'background': 'linear-gradient('+colors[test.number]+','+colors[0]+')'}"
```

So my question is how can I correct the **first code** in order to have an image as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the value is being assigned as a style, but the browser is removing it when it's *invalid*.

Take this example:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'fooBar'}"></div>
```

When I run the above example in Angular. I see this in the browser.

```
<div _ngcontent-c18="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></div>
```

The element is missing the `background` style when I use Chrome's inspector.

This tells me that Angular assigned the invalid CSS style but the browser ignored it.

This raises the question if one of your variables is `undefined`. It could be `colors`, `colors[test.number]`, `colors[0]` or `test.number`.

Try using a function on the component to generate the style object, and logging this value to the console to ensure it's correct.

```
public getBackground(start, end, num) {
    const style = {'background': `linear-gradient(${start},${end}),url(../assets/img/test-${num}.jpg)`};
    console.log(style);
    return style;
}
```

Then in the template

```
<div [ngStyle]="getBackground(colors[test.number],colors[0],test.number)"></div>
```

Comment: I follow your point and I understand the logic behind it. However, that should not be the case since on the same div element I have a `*ngIf="colors?.length > 0"` and a `*ngFor="let test of tests | async"` which both guarantee that the code below will not be executed unless those variable are defined. In my case the divs are actually loaded onto the view and I can see the content with just the background missing. (If I am not mistaken, if the variables were undefined I wouldn't be able to see that component at all). 

Is there a solution you might have in order to deal with this issue?

Comment: @EddyJusufi call a function in the component to generate the style object. Before you return it call `console.log(value)` to output the result. Visually inspect the result to ensure it's correct. When you have expressions like this in the template you can't tell at run-time what the results are.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example on how to generate the style object in JS in order to be able to print it?

Comment: [This is the result](https://i.imgur.com/ncZbRh4.png) I got. After inspecting it, I do not actually see anything wrong with the syntax as it appears to be the same code I have been running in my .css file where it actually is applied correctly.

Comment: @EddyJusufi try removing the relative path from `../assets`. The `assets` folder in Angular is not relative.

Comment: I should feel ashamed. I have missed an extra `../` in my destination folder. Everything is working perfectly fine now. The syntax was correct after all. Thank you for all the help, sir. Thumbs up!